# Use predict() on a dataset with different length

Tags: r, regression, prediction, quantile-regression

I estimated the 0.1 conditional quantile of a linear regression model previously estimated by OLS by applying rq. The original data consists of 8760 rows (hourly data for one year).

```
> require("quantreg")
> Qr_0.1 = rq(Reg_OLS, tau=0.1)
```

I now want to use the estimated model to predict a much smaller timespan:

```
> Qrpredict_0.1 = predict.rq(Qr_0.1, newdata)
```

But it results in the following warning message:

```
Warning message:'newdata' had 192 rows but variables found have 8760 rows
```

The result I get consists of 8760 rows. And it seems like it just uses the old data.

What exactly is the problem here and is there a way to deal with this?

Edit: It works perfectly fine when I use new data with the same number of rows.

Comment: That is a *warning* message not error. Does `predict.rq` not yield a result?

Comment: It yields a result that I do not understand and it consists of 8760 rows so it is definetly not the desired one.

Comment: @Parfait and by the way: It works perfectly fine when I use a new dataframe with the same number of rows.

Comment: Is your `rq()` correct? Where is x, y, or formula? Maybe this affects latter `predict.rq`. Please set up a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)